# XSLT: counting between empty nodes

Tags: xslt, count, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

The Following XML is given (I don't know how many empty `<milestone>` elements there are):

```
<milestone n="a"/>
<seg>bla</seg>
<seg>bla</seg>
<milestone n="b"/>
<seg>bla</seg>
<seg>bla</seg>
```

Needs to be transformed to

```
<milestone n="a"/>
<seg n="1">bla</seg>
<seg n="2">bla</seg>
<milestone n="b"/>
<seg n="1">bla</seg>
<seg n="2">bla</seg>
```

How do I restart counting after I hit an empty element?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="seg">
    <xsl:variable name="counter">
      <xsl:number from="milestone" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <seg>
    <xsl:attribute name="n">
      <xsl:value-of select="$counter"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    </seg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Using an attribute value template `<seg n="{$counter}"><xsl:apply-templates/></seg>` would be a bit more compact or shorter to read and write than using `xsl:attribute`.